# JavaFX custom events with OSGi

Tags: java, javafx, osgi, openjfx

I am developing a JavaFX application which uses the Apache Felix OSGi framework.
My issue is that when trying to register for a custom event the exception shown below is thrown.

```
org.apache.karaf.shell.support.MultiException: Error executing command on bundles:
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class swt6.componentmanager.gui.event.RemoveSensorEvent
    at swt6.componentmanager.gui.ComponentManagerGui.createSensorView(ComponentManagerGui.java:170) ~[?:?]
    at swt6.componentmanager.gui.ComponentManagerGui.createSensorActuatorContainer(ComponentManagerGui.java:159) ~[?:?]
    at swt6.componentmanager.gui.ComponentManagerGui.createRootContainer(ComponentManagerGui.java:91) ~[?:?]
    at swt6.componentmanager.gui.ComponentManagerGui.lambda$start$0(ComponentManagerGui.java:62) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277) ~[?:?]
    ... 1 more
```

The code for registering for the custom event is shown below, too.

```
private Node createSensorView() {
    var container = new VBox();
    container.getChildren().add(JavaFXUtil.createHeading("Sensors"));
    var sensorTable = new SensorsTable(this.sensors);
    sensorTable.addEventHandler(
            RemoveSensorEvent.REMOVE_SENSOR_EVENT_TYPE,
            this::onRemoveSensor
    );
    container.getChildren().add(sensorTable);
    return container;
}
```

The code of the class `RemoveSensorEvent` is also illustrated below.

```
package swt6.componentmanager.gui.event;

import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventType;
import swt6.sensor.Sensor;

public class RemoveSensorEvent extends Event {
    public static final EventType<RemoveSensorEvent> REMOVE_SENSOR_EVENT_TYPE =
            new EventType<>(Event.ANY, "REMOVE_SENSOR");

    private final Sensor sensor;

    public RemoveSensorEvent(Sensor sensor) {
        super(REMOVE_SENSOR_EVENT_TYPE);

        this.sensor = sensor;
    }

    public Sensor getSensor() {
        return this.sensor;
    }
}
```

The bundle which contains the JavaFX code has the following package layout; all these packages are located in the same bundle:

```
swt6.componentmanager.gui
    ComponentManagerGui.java
    swt6.componentmanager.gui.event
        RemoveSensorEvent.java
    swt6.componentmanager.gui.component
    swt6.componentmanager.gui.viewmodel
```

As `RemoveSensorEvent` is part of the package `swt6.componentmanager.gui.event`, which is located within the same bundle as the code invoking it (`swt6.componentmanager.gui.ComponentManagerGui.java`), there should not be any issue with loading the class definition; for instance, classes located in `swt6.componentmanager.gui.component` and `swt6.componentmanager.gui.viewmodel` can be accessed from `swt6.componentmanager.gui` with no problems. Does this have something to do with JavaFX trying to access `RemoveSensorEvent` using reflection?